# Using AngularJS, how do I set all form fields to $dirty at once?

Tags: angularjs

I have created a HTML form using AngularJS and added `required` attributes to some fields.

For these fields, I have an error message that displays if the field is not `$pristine` and also `$invalid`:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="SomeModel.SomeProperty" name="myField" class="input-block-level" required>
<p ng-show="frmMyForm.myField.$invalid && !frmMyForm.myField.$pristine" class="error-text">This field is required!</p>
```

This works fine.  However, if the user simply skips over a required field (never places the cursor in it), then the field is always pristine and therefore the error message isn't displayed, even after clicking the submit button.  So the user is faced with a form they can't submit but no error text to tell them why.

My thought is that setting all form fields to `$dirty` on the submit action would trigger the error messages to show up for any required field that the user simply skipped.  Is this possible?  If so, how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using ng-disabled="frmMyForm.$invalid" on your button? This way your button will be disabled as long as the form is invalid.

Comment: @snaplemouton--Thanks, that's what I did at first, but the problem with that approach is the same: the button is disabled and the user might have no idea why since the validation hasn't triggered (shown the error text).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We do something similar to your answer, we have a formSubmitted directive that binds to the submit event, if fired we set $submitted variable on the form controller. That way you can use it in a similar fashion than how you use ShowValidationMessages but it is re-usable. Very simple directive:

```
app.directive('formSubmitted', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'form',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$submitted = false;
            element.on('submit', function () {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.$submitted = true;
                });
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

You apply this on the form tag itself as an attribute.

We took it a couple of steps further, our requirement was to show validation errors only if the following holds true: the element is invalid AND either the form was submitted OR the input element has blurred. So we ended up with another directive that requires ngModel that sets the blurred status of the element on the ngModel controller.

And finally to get rid of a whole lot of repeated boiler-plate code in html to check all these thing, e.g. your `ng-show="frmMyForm.myField.$invalid && (!frmMyForm.myField.$pristine || MyObject.ShowValidationMessages)"` we encapsulated that into a directive as well. This template directive wraps our input elements with Bootstrap boiler-plate as well as handle all the validation stuff. So now all my form inputs just follow this pattern:

```
<div data-bc-form-group data-label="Username:">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" ng-model="vm.username" data-bc-focus required />
</div>
```

and bcFormGroup directive transforms that into the following bootstrap enabled html:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': showFormGroupError()}" data-bc-form-group="" data-label="Username:">
    <label for="username" class="col-md-3 control-label ng-binding">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" ng-model="vm.username" data-bc-focus="" required="" class="ng-pristine form-control ng-valid ng-valid-required">
        <span class="help-block ng-hide" ng-show="showRequiredError()">Required</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This keep things DRY and offers great flexibility into what type of inputs are supported.

Update:

Here is a basic listing of bcFormGroup directive. The default template uses bootstrap's horizontal form, but can be adapted to your liking.

```
app.directive('bcFormGroup', ['$compile', '$interpolate', function ($compile, $interpolate) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template:
        '<div class="form-group" ng-class="{\'has-error\': showFormGroupError()}">' +
            '<label for="{{inputId}}" class="col-md-3 control-label">{{label}}</label>' +
            '<div class="col-md-9">' +
                '<bc-placeholder></bc-placeholder>' +
            '</div>' +
        '</div>',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    require: '^form',
    scope: {
        label: '@',
        inputTag: '@'
    },

    link: function (scope, element, attrs, formController, transcludeFn) {

        transcludeFn(function (clone) {
            var placeholder = element.find('bc-placeholder');
            placeholder.replaceWith(clone);
        });

        var inputTagType = scope.inputTag || 'input';
        var inputElement = element.find(inputTagType);
        var fqFieldName = formController.$name + '.' + inputElement.attr('name');
        var formScope = inputElement.scope();

        if (inputElement.attr('type') !== 'checkbox' && inputElement.attr('type') !== 'file') {
            inputElement.addClass('form-control');
        }

        scope.inputId = $interpolate(inputElement.attr('id'))(formScope);
        scope.hasError = false;
        scope.submitted = false;

        formScope.$watch(fqFieldName + '.$invalid', function (hasError) {
            scope.hasError = hasError;
        });

        formScope.$watch(formController.$name + '.$submitted', function (submitted) {
            scope.submitted = submitted;
        });

        if (inputElement.attr('data-bc-focus') != null || inputElement.attr('bc-focus') != null) {
            scope.hasBlurred = false;
            formScope.$watch(fqFieldName + '.$hasBlurred', function (hasBlurred) {
                scope.hasBlurred = hasBlurred;
            });
        }

        if (inputElement.attr('required')) {
            scope.hasRequiredError = false;
            formScope.$watch(fqFieldName + '.$error.required', function (required) {
                scope.hasRequiredError = required;
            });
            inputElement.after($compile('<span class="help-block" ng-show="showRequiredError()">Required</span>')(scope));
        }

        if (inputElement.attr('type') === 'email') {
            scope.hasEmailError = false;
            formScope.$watch(fqFieldName + '.$error.email', function (emailError) {
                scope.hasEmailError = emailError;
            });
            inputElement.after($compile('<span class="help-block" ng-show="showEmailError()">Invalid email address</span>')(scope));
        }

        scope.showFormGroupError = function () {
            return scope.hasError && (scope.submitted || (scope.hasBlurred === true));
        };

        scope.showRequiredError = function () {
            return scope.hasRequiredError && (scope.submitted || (scope.hasBlurred === true));
        };

        scope.showEmailError = function () {
            return scope.hasEmailError && (scope.submitted || (scope.hasBlurred === true));
        };

    }
  };
}]);
```

**Update:**

The following directive sets $focused and $hasBlurred:

```
app.directive('bcFocus', [function () {
    var focusClass = 'bc-focused';
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$focused = false;
            ctrl.$hasBlurred = false;
            element.on('focus', function () {
                element.addClass(focusClass);
                var phase = scope.$root.$$phase;
                if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                    ctrl.$focused = true;
                } else {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ctrl.$focused = true;
                    });
                }
            }).on('blur', function () {
                element.removeClass(focusClass);
                var phase = scope.$root.$$phase;
                if (phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
                    ctrl.$focused = false;
                    ctrl.$hasBlurred = true;
                } else {
                    scope.$apply(function () {
                        ctrl.$focused = false;
                        ctrl.$hasBlurred = true;
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Very, very nice.  Thanks!

Comment: Exactly what I need, and probably the best practice for form validation with AngularJS. I'm struggling a bit with the bcFormGroup directive implementation: do you have some code handy?

Comment: @CornelMasson See updated answer, it lists the basics, should give you a good starting point.

Comment: What you do in that case if you need a less standard form? Forms with rows of different width etc. It seems like this code can only generate forms with similar rows...

Comment: @Tsury just adapt the formGroup directive to take the column widths or whatever as properties on the element and this can then be used inside the template. For our use case we only ever needed the same form widths.

Comment: Note that $submitted was added in Angular 1.3, so this answer won't work in earlier versions.

Comment: @Vincent this answer is not reliant on any version of Angular, it will work just fine on 1.2. The only difference is that in 1.2 we create $submitted on the form controller, where in 1.3 and beyond the variable exists already, so we just set the value.

Comment: How do you use the $hasBlurred functionality? In combination with "ng-blur"? I can't get this to work..

Comment: @xtof $hasBlurred is set by another customer directive, see updated answer.

Answer (score 14):

When a form invalidates, the [FormController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) contains an `$error` property.

> `$error` Is an object hash, containing references to controls or forms with failing validators.

So you can simply loop through the error object and use [NgModelController's](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) `$setDirty()` on each control:

```
// "If the name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name."
var form = scope.myForm;

if (form.$invalid) {
    angular.forEach(form.$error, function(controls, errorName) {
        angular.forEach(controls, function(control) {
            control.$setDirty();
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: I actually like this solution a lot. It's fairly concise and doesn't require defining custom directives, while still avoiding having to reference any controls by name in your controller. (BTW, you don't have to use angular.forEach for this to work - you can iterate over the controls however you want - but that's just a matter of preference.)

Comment: As oneliner with fat arrow function: `angular.forEach(form.$error, controls => controls.forEach(control => control.$setDirty()));`

Answer (score 8):

I came up with an answer shortly after posting this.  I am not sure if it is the *correct way*, but it does work.

In your controller, simply add a property for "ShowValidationMessages" or something similar and set it to `false`:

```
$scope.MyObject = {
   ShowValidationMessages: false
};
```

Now reference this value in your field-level validation logic:

```
<p ng-show="frmMyForm.myField.$invalid && (!frmMyForm.myField.$pristine || MyObject.ShowValidationMessages)" class="error-text">This field is required!</p>
```

Finally, toggle the `ShowValidationMessages` property to `true` in your form submit function:

```
    $scope.MyObject = {
       ShowValidationMessages: false,
       SubmitForm: function(){
            $scope.MyObject.ShowValidationMessages = true;
            if($scope.frmMyForm.$valid){
                //do stuff
            }    
       }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I did something simple.

```
 $scope.FormName.InputName.$pristine = false;
if($scope.FormName.$invalid)
return;
```

Comment: I think this works fine, but I would advise against this because it requires referencing form controls by name in your controller, which is generally something to avoid, and it also turns into a lot of code if you have a lot of controls. I would recommend @nick's answer as a cleaner solution based on a similar idea.